# How do I dynamically pick a logo in a shared site when configured on the Partial Design?

Tags: sxa

We have a new set of websites using the Shared Sites (or master site) feature included with SXA 1.7.0. During the design process we realized that each of the sites should have a unique header logo. Based on past projects we know that the header logo is often configured on the header Partial Design.

How do I both share the Partial Design and allow for the site to dynamically pick  the logo?

Answer (score 1):

The SXA Team recommended using a query on the datasource for the image like the following:

`query:$site/Data/Images/Logo`

Each site should have a global datasource item under **Data/Images** with the same item name "Logo". In this way you can easily setup the logo and change on a site-by-site basis. This approach could even be used on sites that are not using the "Shared Sites" feature.

**Note:** We did discuss using the token `$siteMedia` but that resolves to the paths to media folders as specified in the "Additional Children" field on the virtual media folder item. Subsequently that would not meet the need at all or at least not as well as the previous approach.